# Easiest way to return double from another class

Tags: android, class, structure

I wish to return a double from another class depending on input doubles. 
Any good links/examples to very simple project structure examples would be appreciated.
 Am I missing something in manifest.
ie.
activity 1

```
import com.example.app.utils.getRhumbLineBearingUtil;


double tbearing =             getRhumbLineBearing(alata,alona,alatb,alonb);

double recipbearing=getRhumbLineBearing(alatb, alonb, alata, alona);
```

Activity 2
    import com.example.app.utils.getRhumbLineBearingUtil;

```
 double lattocbearing = getRhumbLineBearing(lat,lon,alatc,alonc);

 double bcbearing=getRhumbLineBearing(alatb, alonb, alatc, alonc);
```

(I do this over many activities with 15 different returns with some inputs ie gps points changing rapidly)

Class
    package com.example.app.utils;

```
public class getRhumbLineBearingUtil
{


public double getRhumbLineBearing(double $lat1, double $lon1, double $lat2, double $lon2)
  {Yada=trueRhumb  ;
double Bearing=yada;
Return (bearing);
      }
}
```

I am not interested in bearingTo which is the initial bearing hearing.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Classes don't return values.  Methods do.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Have a method in another class return a value. Is this possible? Or get it back easily or I may have to put this method into every class I use it which will eventually get messy.

Comment: Of course it is.  Do you need class instances (objects) or statics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first learn a bit of Java programming and then move-up to android. You cannot do that that way. Try this:

```
Class GetRhumbLineBearingUtil {    

    public static double getRhumbLineBearing(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        return lat1 + lon1;
    }
}
```

And then in another class, after import and whatever you wanna use that method for, just call it like this:

```
double lattocbearing = GetRhumbLineBearingUtil.getRhumbLineBearing(alatb, alonb, alata, alona);
```

Some notes here: static methods can be accessed via ClassName.methodName

This was what i understood from the question. Now if you want to exchange data between activities, then that is another story, you can use intents.

Some notes tho:

- Class names start with upperCase
- Classes, methods and method arguments should have a proper name/meaning to make it easier to understand what is being done.
- Variable names start lowerCase
- There is no `$variable` in Java, everything is passed by value
- If you want to return some value stored in a variable in class `GetRhumbLineBearingUtil` you need to make that variables static as well.

Comment: I am learning, the app works but am trying to make the code and structure more readable and efficient. I spent ages yesterday researching and the last five minutes laughing at myself. So simple.

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is how to exchange data between two activities and you would like to pass some double values, you should use the method `putExtra(String name, double value)` or `putExtra(String name, double[] value)` and get them from the second activity `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method.

Otherwise use a static method that contains your method code.

```
public class Utils {

public static double getRhumbLineBearing(double latA, double lonA, double latB, double lonB) {
    [your code]
}
}
```