# String to double method

Tags: android

This might be a very simple questions but i cant find a hint anywhere.

I have check the below links but still cannot find what is wrong with my code.
[Returning a double from a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614479/returning-a-double-from-a-method)
[Easiest way to return double from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159804/easiest-way-to-return-double-from-another-class)

What i want is to return a method that return a 2 decimal double.

Call the below method but it is not running.

```
toDouble(double1);//the result are not 2 decimals
edittext.setText(String.valueOf(double1));

public double toDouble(double d){
  String str = String.format("%1.2f", d);
  d = Double.valueOf(str);
  return d;
}
```

It work well when i code like this

```
  String str = String.format("%1.2f", double1);
  double1 = Double.valueOf(str);
```

Anyone can guide me in this?

Edit 1
If anyone reading this. It is a silly mistake.
**Forgot to define the double

```
double1 = toDouble(double1);//the result are not 2 decimals
edittext.setText(String.valueOf(double1));
```

Comment: "not running" means?

Comment: If this is for some monetary value it is better to use BigDecimal instead. This class allows fine control over rounding.

Comment: You're not assigning the return value of `toDouble(double1)` to anything or printing it. Did you just miss it?

Comment: @Tim Not running means the double i set to textview are still with lots of decimals instead of 2.

Comment: textView.setText(toDouble(double1) + "");  try like this.

Comment: double parsedDouble = toDouble(double1);
edittext.setText(String.valueOf(parsedDouble));

Use this line

Comment: @Al-Amin yes that does solve it. double1=toDouble(double1);

Comment: :)  Happy coding. :)

Comment: thanks! it is a great help!

Comment: looks like you are missing Java basics. Pleas epass through some Java basic tutorial about how to use methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass the value to your method, you by mistake set value directly inside settext

the below code is wrong

```
edittext.setText(String.valueOf(double1));
```

instead you should write

```
edittext.setText(String.valueOf(toDouble(double1)));
```

Comment: yep, solved it. just done it by edittext.setText(String.valueOf(toDouble(double1)));

Answer (score 1):

Simply do it in a single line:

```
edittext.setText(String.valueOf(toDouble(double1)))
```